# How to build angular 4 apps in nginx or apache httpd?

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-cli, auth0

Hi I am trying to build the Angular 4 app, steps followed is below -

Build `ng build`

In my amazon ec2 instance I am running apache. Steps followed -

```
#!/bin/bash
yum install httpd -y
yum update -y
cp dist/* /var/www/html/
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
```

Everything works but my app is using `auth0` for authentication, I see they do callback to `http://ip/callback`

My Application says - 404 Not found.

[image: app-problem]

I tried to build like `ng build --base-href .`, it didnt worked`!
Please help me how to build this one, please note that when I use`ng serve` in my local everything works awesome. but when I am trying to deploy to production its giving this error. I am pretty sure something wrong I am doing while building the app.

I tried `nginx` docker container, it gives the same error. My docker file looks like this.

`FROM nginx
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html`

1. docker build -t ng-auth0-web-dev .
2. docker run -d -p 8080:80 ng-auth0-web-dev

Anything wrong in above docker file?

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples/tree/master/01-Login - sample app code

> https://manage.auth0.com/#/logs - No error in logs, that means auth0 is working fine but I am getting build error with angular.

Exact error:

[image]

[image: auth0 callback settings]

Update -

I tried building like this also - 
`ng build --base-href http://34.213.164.54/`
and `ng build --base-href http://34.213.164.54:80/`, but same error.

**So the problem is Narrowed down to How I am building the Angular App**

```
public handleAuthentication(): void {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this.setSession(authResult);
          localStorage.setItem('email', profile.email);
          this.verticofactoryService.registerUser(u);
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        });



      } else if (err) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        console.log(err);
        alert(`Error: ${err.error}. Check the console for further details.`);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why do you expect a request to /callback to give anything other than a 404? Have you configured Apache to serve anything for that URL?

Comment: yes I am requesting so that the /callback will verify the users. I did not configured anything in apache. I followed exact above steps nothing else. can you give me an example ?

Comment: An example of what? What is supposed to happen when a request to /callback comes to your server?

Comment: It will handle the authentication, I have updated the post with the snippet, in short, it will navigate to the home page.

Comment: You don't get it. If you don't configure the server to serve somthing for the url /callback, it won't serve anything for that URL. All your server has is a bunch or static files (like index.html). It won't serve anything other than those static files unless you configure it to do so. Read https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: What component does your router call when /callback is requested?  Can you paste that code into your Question?  Solving the apache/nginx issue might only be the first part of your problem.

Comment: @Graham - Auth Component - The source code which I am using is here -
 https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples/tree/master/02-User-Profile

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I wasn't sure if you were using that sample or not.

Comment: I am trying like @JBNizet mentioned.  any one  know where to find `try_files` in nginx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular apps are perfect candidates for serving with a simple static HTML server. You don't need a server-side engine to dynamically compose application pages because Angular does that on the client-side.

If the app uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have.

Suppose in your nginx server conf just add some thing like this. `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Reference - https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples/tree/master/02-User-Profile

Thank you JB Nizet, it worked finally.

[image: server conf]